# How to use fillSelectors in casperjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I need to get some content from the page, but if I use `fillSelectors()` the content is not load. Maybe i need use `evaluate()`, but i dont undestend where and how.

```
var casper = require('casper').create()
casper.start('http://console.matomycontentnetwork.com/', function() {
  this.fillSelectors('form#login-form', {
      'input[name="username"]':    'jpost',
      'input[name="password"]':    'matomy123'
  }, true);
  this.clickLabel("Sign In", 'button');
});

casper.then(function() {
  var start_date = '09/01/2015';
  var end_date = '10/07/2015';
  this.evaluate(function() {
    $('#report-range').val('custom').change();
  });

  this.fillSelectors('form#report-form', {          
    'input[name="report[start_date]"]': start_date,
    'input[name="report[end_date]"]':  end_date,
    'input[id="grouping-option-3"]' : true,
    'input[id="grouping-option-2"]' : true,
    'input[id="grouping-option-4"]' : true
  }, true);

  this.click("#run-report");
  this.wait(10000, function () {
    this.echo('.geo_country_name.innerText: ' + this.evaluate(function() {
      return document.querySelector('.geo_country_name').innerText;
    }));
    this.echo('td.alignright:nth-child(5).innerText: ' + this.evaluate(function() {
      return document.querySelector('td.alignright:nth-child(5)').innerText;
    }));
  });
});

casper.run();
```

Can you help with that?

Comment: I don't have an account. Why don't you describe what is supposed to happen and what is happening? Which step didn't work? What do you see when you save multiple screenshots with `casper.capture(filename)`? Don't forget to [edit] your question to add the minimal markup to help diagnose the problem.

Comment: @drescherjm, in the code: username: 'jpost', password : 'matomy123'. If delete this part `this.fillSelectors('form#report-form', {          
    'input[name="report[start_date]"]': start_date,
    'input[name="report[end_date]"]':  end_date,
    'input[id="grouping-option-3"]' : true,
    'input[id="grouping-option-2"]' : true,
    'input[id="grouping-option-4"]' : true
  }, true);`
then this part returns any data `this.echo('td.alignright:nth-child(5).innerText: ' + this.evaluate(function() {
      return document.querySelector('td.alignright:nth-child(5)').innerText;
    }));`

Comment: That doesn't clear things up. Still don't see where the problem seems to be. Please describe the problem in detail and see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) which applies largely to your case.

Comment: After `this.click("#run-report");` in `this.wait()` selector `td.alignright:nth-child(5)` return some data, but if i use `this.fillSelectors()` before `this.click("#run-report");`, this selector is null. Thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some guesses:

If you want to click on some button to submit a form, don't automatically submit a form. Remove the last argument:

```
this.fillSelectors('form#report-form', {          
    'input[name="report[start_date]"]': start_date,
    'input[name="report[end_date]"]':  end_date,
    'input[id="grouping-option-3"]' : true,
    'input[id="grouping-option-2"]' : true,
    'input[id="grouping-option-4"]' : true
});
```

PhantomJS doesn't support `element.innerText`. You need to use `element.textContent`.

Comment: Thanks, this helped! `fillSelectors()` inside the `casper.start()` working with the last argument and it confuses me. Thank you very much.