# casperjs fill form doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, phantomjs, casperjs

I have a problem with casperjs.

I want to fill a form but casperjs says the form is not found... In the code I can't see  a form name so I tried to use the formid without success

Here is the source code of the website where I want to fill the form

```
<tr class="wcontent" valign="top">
<td></td>
<td id="wcontent_login" class="widgetMiddleMiddle" style="display: block; height: 213px;">
<iframe frameborder="no" src="/WebInt.nsf/loginWidget.xsp?widgetUniqueId=anonymous-login-default" scrolling="no">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <body class="xspView tundra">
    <form id="view:_id1" class="xspForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/GI7/WebInt.nsf/loginWidget.xsp?widgetUniqueId=anonymous-login-default" method="post">
    <div id="inactive_loginWidget">
    <div class="inactive_loginLeft">Anmeldung</div>    
    <div class="inactive_loginRight">
    <div style="height:27px;background-color:#004178;color:white;padding:10px;    width:227px;margin-bottom:5px;text-align:center;">
    <div>
        <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Benutzername" onkeypress="return handleKeyPressed(event)" onfocus="var elem =     document.getElementById(''); if(elem != null) {hideLabel(elem, 'username');}" onblur="var elem = document.getElementById(''); if(elem != null) {if(document.getElementById('username').value == '') { showLabel(elem); } else { hideLabel(elem); }}" name="username" autocomplete="off" vk_19ae7="subscribed">
    </div>
    <div class="cleaner3px"></div>
<div>
    <div class="cleaner3px"></div>
    <div title="Anzahl der Spalten für die Darstellungsbreite des Browsers einstellen.">
    <div class="cleaner10px"></div>
    <div class="button" style="margin-left: -5px; cursor: default;"     onmouseover="setHoverEffectButton(this, '');"     onmouseout="resetHoverEffectButton(this, '');"     onmousedown="setPressedButtonEffect(this, '');"     onclick="handleKeyPressed(event, true)">
    </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <input id="view:_id1__VUID" type="hidden" value="!1k37604fezbng88zt78ksqv5x!" name="$$viewid">
    <input type="hidden" name="$$xspsubmitid">
    <input type="hidden" name="$$xspexecid">
    <input type="hidden" name="$$xspsubmitvalue">
    <input type="hidden" name="$$xspsubmitscroll">
    <input type="hidden" value="view:_id1" name="view:_id1">
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

My casperjs Code

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: "debug"
});
function wait5seconds() {
    casper.wait(5000, function() {
    this.echo('2');    
    });
}

//    casper.options.waitTimeout = 40000;

casper.start("https://Testseite.de/WebInt.nsf/loginWidget.xsp", function() {
    this.echo("Page title: " + (this.getTitle()));
    wait5seconds();
});

casper.then(function(){
    this.fillSelector('Formname ????', {
    'username':    'Hans',
    'password':    'Wurst'
    }, true);
});

casper.then(function() {
        casper.capture('Test2.png');
});

casper.then(function() {
    this.evaluate(function(){
    //trigger click event on submit button
    document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]').click();
    });
});
casper.then(function() {
    casper.capture('Test3.png');
});

casper.run();
```

I also tried to solve my problem with queryselector but still no success :(

Comment: This is an English language website. Please change your question to use English.

Comment: I translated it sorry for the wrong language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved it with an debugger and Post request:

```
casper.open('https://XXX/WebInt.nsf',
{
    method: 'post',
    data: {'username':'XX','password':'XX'}
    }, function(response){
    if(response.status == 200){
        require('utils').dump(this.page.content);
    }
});
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing 'form; from the selector.

Something along the lines of:

```
this.fillSelectors('form#view:_id1', {      
    casper.then(function(){
        this.fillSelector('Formname ????', {
                          'username':    'Hans',
                          'password':    'Wurst'
    }, true);
});
```

This question might help: [How to use fillSelectors in casperjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33033639/how-to-use-fillselectors-in-casperjs)

Answer (score 0):

Yes but every time i start the Test it breaks in step 4 :

```
casper.then(function(){
     this.echo("Formstart");
    this.fillSelector('form#view:_id1', {
            'username':    'XX',
            'password':    'XX'
    },true);
     this.echo("Formend");
});
```

Formstart works but Formend does not get printed so the mistake must be there .... 
I changed it now to :

```
casper.then(function(){
    this.echo("Formstart");
    this.fillSelector('form#view:_id1', {
            'input[name="username"]':    'XX',
            'input[name="password"]':    'Xx'
    },true);
    this.echo("Formend");

});
```

but still no success :(

Comment: The only formname i got is the view:_id1

Comment: I tried this :   this.fillSelector('form[id=view:_id1] now .. no success